# How to minimize Windows Media Player to system tray?

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

Is there a workaround for this? I try a Google search and find one called wmptrayplugin.zip could not find link that worked.

Comment: Which version of WMP?

Comment: The built-in one for Windows 7